# The latest kernel update broke my Macbook Air; how can I fix it?

Tags: boot, kernel, mac, downgrade

I installed 12.10 on my 11-inch mid-'11 Air without a hitch. I removed Unity and installed Cinnamon in its place. I purged every Unity-related package from the system. Today, the kernel updated and broke my machine. I can't get to the GRUB menu and I am told that the computer is running in low-graphics mode, even though I can't do anything with the options presented by the dialogues. nmcli refuses to connect to my network. I need a way to get the system working again, preferably without using a reinstall or install disk.

`lspci -nn | grep VGA` produces:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corp. 2nd Gen. Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)`

[X Log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1471296/)

A *Happy* Update!

Turns out my problem was I never ran update-grub. So right now, I'm rebooting with Unity installed again to see if it makes a difference.

A Happier Update

The problem now seems to lie with the new kernel. It won't recognize my wireless card. But this problem can be considered closed, methinks.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Try to boot into your older kernel. Hold Shift very early during booting and you should be able to get into your Grub menu. You say you "can't get to" it, but that does not sound plausible as your system *does* boot. If the older kernel does boot correctly, you can provide more information.

Comment: @gertvdijk I held Shift through the entire boot. No luck.

Comment: @iSeth: added some stuff

Answer (score 2):

jaacarmac [solved the problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/233423/44179) in his post:

> A Happy Update!
>
> Turns out my problem was I never ran update-grub. So right now, I'm rebooting with Unity installed again to see if it makes a difference.
>
> A Happier Update
>
> The problem now seems to lie with the new kernel. It won't recognize my wireless card. But this problem can be considered closed, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

When something like this happens to me, I usually boot from an older kernel image - which I choose in the GRUB menu as @gertvdijk already suggested.

Since you don't see the GRUB menu, I recommend you take a look at your conf file:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

(or substitute with an editor you're comfortable with - nano, emacs...) Check what your values for `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEPUT` are. If you're ending up with a shell, you must have passed through GRUB. If nothing else works, try setting your `GRUB_DEFAULT` value to something other than 0 - probably 1 (try experimenting until you pin-point the correct kernel image).

Once you're done editing the file, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to apply the changes.

If this works, a fix will probably be out by the next kernel version, but you can help the process by checking to see if you can report this bug.